# Angular $http.get.error crossed in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phpstorm

I'm starting to use PhpStorm in my development. I have an issue with an Angular 1.5 project.

When I write an `$http.get(url).success().error();` error is crossed and PhpStorm shows a warning because error is deprecated in js.

How can I solve this?

I already added Angularjs as library in my project.

Comment: use `then` instead of `success` and `error` callbacks. [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's angular's documentation on this issue:

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been deprecated. Use the standard then method instead.

The `then` function allows you to handle both success and error situations in promise based functions:

```
$http.get(url).then(function(response) {
    // handle promise resolve...
}, function(error) {
    // handle promise reject...
})
```